# autotools for pthreads not setting correct linker flags

Tags: pthreads, autotools

I am adding some pthreads code into my Linux application that I'm building with autotools. I was getting an error about not linking in libpthreads. So I want to specify the pthreads dependency and compiler/linker flags in autotools.

I found [some references](http://airtower.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/autotools-and-pthreads/) that say use an [`ACX_PTHREAD` macro](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/ac-archive/acx_pthread.html). GNU provides an [`AX_PTHREAD` macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_pthread.html). Both are very similar in concept. But I've tried both (on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit), and found that they set `-pthread` in `$PTHREAD_CFLAGS`, but for some reason they don't set the `-lpthread` linker flag in `$PTHREAD_LIBS`.

The build fails. When I run `make`, I get:

```
...
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2   -o myapp main.o ... -lconfuse   -llog4cpp -lnsl   -lpopt   -lfuse    -L/usr/local/lib -lrt 
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/myapp main.o ...  -lconfuse -llog4cpp -lnsl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so -lfuse -L/usr/local/lib -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: app-fuse.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_kill@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'pthread_kill@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

In this case, the `./configure` step shows:

```
...
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
...
```

I notice it checks for `-lpthreads`, but shouldn't it be checking for `-lpthread`?

I've found that I can use:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(pthread, pthread_create, [PTHREAD_LIBS+=-lpthread])
```

and then the build succeeds. But I assume this isn't the best way to make it work on the widest variety of platforms.

I see Ubuntu also has a [package `libpthread-stubs0-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpthread-stubs0-dev). But I'm not sure what it's for.

What is the "right way" to use pthreads with autotools?

Comment: `ACX_` macros were renamed to `AX_` in the GNU Autoconf Archive on 2009-08-06

Comment: I found that ACX_PTHREAD is using -lpthreads on my system the correct libname is -lpthread without the S. Check your config.log for /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads

Comment: the ax_pthread.m4 file does the right thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Simons who asked on the autoconf mailing list, we have a somewhat [official answer](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf-archive-maintainers/2013-06/msg00021.html):

> Compiler flags and linker flags are not mutually-exclusive sets, not
>   least because linking is typically done via the compiler frontend (cc)
>   and not by invoking the linker (ld) directly. Any flags that you can
>   use in the compile step (e.g. -O2, -DFOO, -I/tmp/include) will
>   generally be accepted in the linking step, even if it's not applicable
>   then. (The reverse may not be true, e.g. -lfoo.)
>
> Given that, it's a lot less error-prone to use PTHREAD_CFLAGS (and
>   other CFLAGS variables) when linking, rather than duplicating the
>   applicable flags into PTHREAD_LIBS/LDFLAGS/etc. variables and not
>   using any CFLAGS variables then.

So just use PTHREAD_CFLAGS for your linker, too.

Comment: *"So just use `PTHREAD_CFLAGS`..."* - This is a C++ library; he should not be using `CFLAGS`. He should be usign `CXXFLAGS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this same issue when I added a first C++ source to an otherwise working C project (a shared library). Adding this C++ file caused libtool to switch from linking with gcc to linking with g++. Seems that linking with gcc a '-pthread' is enough to add the dynamic dependency to libpthread, but when linking with g++, it is not.

I tried with the above patch to a local ax_pthread.m4, but this didn't help. Passing '-lpthread' to g++ would fix the issue.

Edit: for some reason, ax_pthread.m4 forces C as the test language even if the AC_LANG is set as C++. This patch makes things work for me:

```
--- m4/ax_pthread.m4_orig   2013-06-15 20:03:36.000000000 +0300
+++ m4/ax_pthread.m4    2013-06-15 20:03:51.000000000 +0300
@@ -87,7 +87,6 @@
 AU_ALIAS([ACX_PTHREAD], [AX_PTHREAD])
 AC_DEFUN([AX_PTHREAD], [
 AC_REQUIRE([AC_CANONICAL_HOST])
-AC_LANG_PUSH([C])
 ax_pthread_ok=no

 # We used to check for pthread.h first, but this fails if pthread.h
@@ -313,5 +312,4 @@
         ax_pthread_ok=no
         $2
fi
-AC_LANG_POP
 ])dnl AX_PTHREAD
```

Comment: *"Edit: for some reason, ax_pthread.m4 forces C as the test language even if the AC_LANG is set as C++...."* - I hope you filed a bug. Dealing with Autotools and its penchant for ignoring our C++ settings is getting old rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `AX_PTHREAD` macro is finding the `-pthread` compiler flag, and using that. But it looks as though for that particular flag, it should be specified to the linker as well (it apparently does the equivalent of `-lpthread` in the linker). I modified the macro as follows, so that the `-pthread` flag is specified as a linker flag too:

```
diff --git a/m4/ax_pthread.m4 b/m4/ax_pthread.m4
index 6d400ed..f426654 100644
--- a/m4/ax_pthread.m4
+++ b/m4/ax_pthread.m4
@@ -172,6 +172,12 @@ for flag in $ax_pthread_flags; do
                 AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether pthreads work without any flags])
                 ;;

+                -pthread)
+                AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether pthreads work with $flag])
+                PTHREAD_CFLAGS="$flag"
+                PTHREAD_LIBS="$flag"
+                ;;
+
                 -*)
                 AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether pthreads work with $flag])
                 PTHREAD_CFLAGS="$flag"
```

I guess I should submit this to the macro authors.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on a suggestion above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253318/221802) with exact script, this error went away for me after updating my PKbuild.sh script with pthread args:

```
./bootstrap && \
    CPPFLAGS=" -g3 -Wall -pthread "\
    CFLAGS=" -pthread -g3 -Wall "\
    LDFLAGS=" -lpthread "\
    ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode \
        --enable-debug \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --mandir=/usr/share/man \
        --enable-pie           \
    --prefix=/usr          \
    --enable-library       \
    --enable-test          \
    ......... [and so on]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the advice from another post: [autoconf with -pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699113/autoconf-with-pthread)

Here they mentioned you could download this file:

http://svn.sleuthkit.org/repos/sleuthkit/trunk/configure.ac

Place it into your m4 directory.

Then include this in your configure.ac:

```
ACX_PTHREAD
```

Finally, add this to your Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main

main_SOURCES = main.c
main_CFLAGS = $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS)
main_LDADD = $(PTHREAD_LIBS)
```